# How to target angular material stepper padding with CSS?

Tags: css, angular-material2

I am trying to decrease the padding, on an angular material stepper component, since I am developing a compact from this:

[image]

To remove the padding here:

[image]

Ibn the official angular material documentation, they point out that you should create a specific selector. I just don't know how to do that. I have tried the following:

In the chrome tools, I have found a CSS class `.mat-horizontal-stepper-header`. I am trying to decrease the padding from 24 pixels to 10px like this:

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
  padding: 14px !important;
}
```

It does not work. I have created a [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fg92nq), to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Add this css to `style.css`

```
.mat-stepper-horizontal .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
    padding: 10px;
    height:auto;
}
.mat-stepper-horizontal .mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    margin: 0 -4px; 
}
```

Comment: The provided styles do not affect the stepper :(

Comment: But I have applied this css in this link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fg92nq?file=styles.css it's working.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I m using Firefox and also tested in chrome there is no issue and this is not any browser issue.

Comment: I updated the question with a better description of what padding I looking for, almost there :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169983/discussion-between-dauledk-and-ankita-patel).